# Write/read SVN files to external files in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am using Eclipse with subclipse plugin for SVN is there away to write the committed files starting with comment "Ticket ID:" to external file(I need to get the affect files of specific change ).
I mean any committed files starting with this command should be write to committed_file.txt  and if I have svn_file.txt which have files paths is there away to tell Eclipse to take SVN sync. only for this files ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the command line client:

`svn log --search "Ticket ID:" -v > committed_file.txt`

Subclipse can output the history to a file by selecting revisions in the History view and choosing the Generate changelog option, but it does not have a filter mechanism to search the text first.